# onStop is not called in Fragment which is added to android.R.id.content

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm adding the fragment using `android.R.id.content` in order to fill up Activity's space using the following code.

```
private void doFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom_y, R.anim.slide_out_bottom_y,
        R.anim.slide_in_bottom_y, R.anim.slide_out_bottom_y);
    transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, tag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

And I have got a problem to catch the moment that the fragment is closed by pressing back button. The lifecycle method `onStop` is not called.

What I should do in order to make it working properly that all lifecycle methods are called?

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can work on activity onBackPressed() like below

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        val frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.container);
        if (frag is HomeFragment) {
            Fragment currentFragment = (HomeFragment) frag;
            //do your code
            return
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: That's what I exactly did to catch the moment when fragment is closed. But my question is about why `onStop` is not called.